# R: Multible line in a plot using curveid

Tags: r, plot

I'm researcher and not a programmer.

I have often used the `drc` package, to analyze data. There you can define a curveid and it will plot multiple lines in one plot.

I need the same thing just for the normal plot, but obviously is my knowledge to little to do that :(

My data looks like this:

```
  Time        Type   Material      Value1      Value2
1    1          A          X          34        123
1    3          A          X          44        164
1    1          B          X          56        234
1    2          B          X          23        145
1    3          B          X          45        343
1    1          A          Y          45        243

...
```

Now I want e.g first a plot Value1 ~ Time, and for every Material a own line. Then maybe Value2 ~ Time and for every Type a own line.

May intention is a scrip where you at the beginning declare which column contain the x, which the y and which the curveid. And it will plot it like the `drc` package.

I try to use `split()` and `subset` and then `cbind` and `matplot`, but I had problems because there are sometimes Time values missing.

I also wanted to try `reshape2`, but a couldn't install the package.

Is there some simpler solution (similar to the `drc`) package?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The ggplot2 package can do this with `ggplot(yourdata, aes(x = Time, y = Value1, color = Material)) + geom_line()`. (Replace `Value1` with `Value2` and `Material` with `Type` for your second plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicated (Material, Types) cases, lines does not appear appropriated. Try this, using points.

```
tms=range(df[,"Time"])
ylims=range(df[,c("Value1","Value2")])
plot(NA,type="n",xlim=tms,ylim=ylims,xlab="Time",ylab="Val")
df=df[with(df,order(Material,Time)),]
mats=unique(df$Material)
sapply(1:length(mats),function(ma){points(df[df$Material==mats[ma],"Time"],
                        df[df$Material==mats[ma],"Value1"],
                         col=ma,pch=15  )
})
df=df[with(df,order(Type,Time)),]
library(RColorBrewer)
coly<-brewer.pal(8,"Accent")[8:1]
typs=unique(df$Type)
sapply(1:length(typs),function(ma){points(df[df$Type==typs[ma],"Time"],
                                           df[df$Type==typs[ma],"Value2"],
                                         col=coly[ma],pch=15+ma  )
})
legend("top",c(mats,typs),pch=c(rep(15,length(mats)),15+1:length(typs)),
       col=c(palette()[1:length(mats)],coly[1:length(typs)]),horiz=T)
```

You will have

[image]